# Ex compatibility with Ed

Tags: script, compatibility, text-editors

I have a script for classic `ed`. Can I run it with `ex`?

I am using Vim's `ex`, but I might also use `nvi` (NVi) or `nvim` (NeoVim).

**NOTE**: Why isn't the code pasted here? I am asking for general compatibility.

Comment: You are going to have to modify your question, in it's current form, it's not clear what your actual question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things I came up with off the cuff (and tested):

- Probably the biggest one: `ed` treats `,` (e.g., `,p`) as meaning `1,$`;
  `ex` seems to treat it as **`.`**. 
  [grawity points out](https://superuser.com/a/1229563/354511#comment1799438_1229563) that `%` means `1,$` in `ex`. 
  Contrary to grawity’s experience, `%` works in my copy of `ed`.
- `ed` uses `n` to display line(s) with line number(s). 
  `ex` uses `nu`.
  *Neither one accepts the other one's syntax.*
- `ed` quits without saving if you say `q` two times in a row. 
  `ex` quits without saving if you say `q!`. 
  *Neither one accepts the other one's syntax.*
- Probably *not* an issue for a script: in `ed`,
  the `P` (capital <kbd>P</kbd>) command turns on prompting. 
  `ex` prompts by default and uses `P` for “put”. 
  If you do this at the beginning of a script,
  the buffers are probably empty,
  and `P` will generate an error message but do no harm. 
  In the unlikely event that you use `P` in the middle of a script,
  this could cause damage.

Answer (score 1):

#### I have a script for classic ed. Can I run it with ex?

You should be able to as `ex` is a superset of `ed`:

> Ex is the root of a family of editors: edit, ex and vi. **Ex is a superset of ed**, with the most notable extension being a display editing facility.

Source [EX (1)](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/ex.html)

Comment: But is it strictly a superset in terms of accepted commands, and not just in terms of functionality? For example, it doesn't seem to accept `,` as an address like Ed would (only `%` which Ed doesn't).

Comment: @grawity I've no idea. I'm going by the manual page :)